# Implementing an iterable Python class with descriptors/properties

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am attempting to create an iterable python class to represent line segments in a finite element model of cable. My algorithm takes a list of LineSegment instances and then builds a numerical model. The reason I want to be able to iterate through the class is so that I can use a PyQt QTableView to display and modify LineSegment instances. So far this works perfectly. Everything can be displayed and modified in a QTableView.

However, I have have recently been tasked with handling physical units (I am using the awesome Pint library for unit handling). I would like to implement getters and setters to help handle this.

I initially tried using properties but found that they are not added to the `__dict__`. I then tried descriptor, and while they can be added to the `__dict__` I found that when iterating through the class the get and set methods are ignored.

My base class I inherit from is below. This creates a class that is much like a Python dictionary.

```
from collections import MutableMapping

class DictLikeBaseClass(MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.__dict__[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.__dict__[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__dict__)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__dict__)
```

My descriptor class is shown below.

```
from pint import UnitRegistry
ur = UnitRegistry()

class LineProperty:
    def __init__(self, name, unit):
        self.name = name
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = None

    def __set__(self, instance, value):

        # DO STUFF

        # Set a new value with the given unit
        new_value = value * ur[self.unit]
        print('setting {} to {}'.format(self.name, new_value))
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = new_value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):

        # DO STUFF

        print('getting {}'.format(instance.__dict__[self.name]))
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]
```

And finally a very stripped down version of my LineSegment class is provided below.

```
 class LineSegment(DictLikeBaseClass):
    unit_weight = LineProperty('unit_weight', 'pound/foot')
    length = LineProperty('length', 'foot')
    diameter = LineProperty('diameter', 'inch')

    def __init__(self, unit_weight, length, diameter):
        super().__init__()
        self.unit_weight = unit_weight
        self.length = length
        self.diameter = diameter
```

This works if the attributes are accessed a via dot a lookup. However, if properties are iterated through they seem to be grabbed straight from the `__dict__` and the `__get__` and `__set__` methods in the descriptor are ignored.

Usage:

```
>>> myLine = LineSegment(unit_weight=2, length=10, diameter=3.0)
setting unit_weight to 2.0 lb/ft
setting length to 10 ft
setting diameter to 3.0 in
```

Getting and setting attributes by dot lookup works, meaning the `__get__` and `__set__` methods in the descriptor are used.

```
>>> myLine.length
getting length
<Quantity(10, 'foot')>

>>> myLine.length = 15
setting length to 15 ft
```

Getting and setting attributes with a dict like lookup ignores the `__get__` and `__set__` methods in the descriptor

```
>>> myLine['length'] = 20
>>> myLine['length']
20
```

it follows that iterating through the class also ignores the `__get__` and `__set__` methods in the descriptor. Which is where this all falls apart as the QTableView requires an iterable type.

```
>>> for k, v in myLine.items():
...     print(k, v)
...
diameter 3.0 in
length 20
unit_weight 2.0 lb/ft
```

---

1. Is there a way to make an iterable class with getters and setters in Python?
2. Am I attempting to do things that are 'unpythonic'?

### -----------------

**EDIT:**

Looking backing. I don't think I was explicit on how QTableView/QTableModel iterates through the class to populate the table.

In QAbstractTableModel you have to implement a method that returns values based on an index object that has a column and row iterator.  So the method to populate the table looks something like this.

```
def data(self, index):
   keys = ['diameter', 'length', 'unit_weight']
   return self._lineSegments[index.column()][keys[index.row()]]
```

where `_lineSegments` is a list of LineSegment instances

The following is a decent proxy of the method for experimenting purposes.

```
myLine = [LineSegment(unit_weight=2, length=10, diameter=3.0), LineSegment(unit_weight=5, length=15, diameter=2.0)]

keys = ['diameter', 'length', 'unit_weight']

for i, _ in enumerate(myLine):
    for j, _ in enumerate(keys):
        print(myLine[i][keys[j]])
```

I guess what I am really looking for is a way to call the getters and setters in the descriptor with a key lookup in the LineSegment class as a opposed to a dot lookup. I am not sure if this is possible in Python...

Comment: I think I am missing something. Why not just implement `myLine.items` to return items as you wish?

Comment: Looks like you might be trying to reinvent [attrdict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrdict/2.0.0).

Comment: @ekhumoro I just tried attrdict. It has the same behavior as my implementation. I guess what I am looking for is way to call the get and set methods in the descriptor with a key lookup instead of a dot lookup.

Comment: @Terraneng. After your recent edit, I fail to see why a `LineSegment` needs to be a mapping, or why you would ever need to iterate over one. Get rid of the `DictLikeBaseClass` and just inherit from `object`. If you want to access an attribute by key, you can simply do e.g. `getattr(linesegment, 'length')`. And the same goes for `setattr` and `delattr` (but I doubt you'll ever actually need these). Personally, I would also get rid of the descriptors, and just use properties (with `get/set` and no `del`).

Comment: @ekhumoro See, I knew what I was doing felt wrong and unpythonic. I just followed your advice and it appears to work nicely. I don't know why I didn't think about getattr! I haven't plugged it into my QAbtstractTableModel yet but it appears that it will work. Once I confirm that it works I'll answer my own question. Thanks